# Instantiate other AngularJS-controller with a CommonController when using IIFE

Tags: angularjs

I have a project where a lot of the models are going to be managed by almost the same controller-code with the only exception that they are calling different services.

The way I'm handling this now is by instantiating a Crud-Controller with common code into every custom controller and then redirecting the service-call by changing the variable inside the custom controller. I.e. 
`vm.service.get()` inside the Crud-Controller changes by setting `vm.service = teamService;` in a custom controller.

This is how I instantiate the Crud-Controller into my custom controllers at the moment:

```
$injector.invoke(Crud, this, {$scope:$scope});
```

This works fine, however I don't know if this is the right way to share common controller code. Maybe it is possible to instantiate a service for this use? Because the question I have (if my way of doing it is correct), how do I access other controllers while using IIFE? Right now I am not using IIFE since I have not figured out a way to do so.

I have tried with `angular.module('app').controller('Crud')` but it does not work.

I.e: How do I get access to the PrimaryCtrl's edit function without using $injector or relying on the $scope inheritance?
http://jsfiddle.net/tcVhN/62/

Comment: Please, provide the code that explains the statements, a couple of lines isn't enough.

Comment: I.e: How do I get access to the PrimaryCtrl's edit function without using $injector or relying on the $scope inheritance?
http://jsfiddle.net/tcVhN/50/

Comment: your service doesn't make sense.  in `fetchUsers`, for example, you are checking if `users` exists, and if it is, you are rejecting the promise with an error, which means if users was in the cache already, you aren't returning anything.

Comment: @user2624679 I see. This is the primary reason why controllerAs is there. Dismiss $scope for everything except scope $* stuff, use `this` instead and extend controllers with JS from common function or class.

Comment: @Claies Sorry. I used an old link. Correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/tcVhN/62/

Comment: @estus So sorry. I used an old link. Correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/tcVhN/62/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your example uses Angular 1.0.x that supports global controllers out of the box. [That's how it would be done](http://jsfiddle.net/prnwky1f/) with more recent Angular, without going too deep into the perils of JS inheritance.

```
'use strict';

(function (root, angular) {
    root.ctrls = root.ctrls || {};

    var primaryCtrl = function ($scope) {
        var self = this;
        console.log('primaryCtrl constructor', self, $scope);
    };
    primaryCtrl.prototype = {
        items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2'],
        edit: function (item) {
            //do stuff
        }
    };
    primaryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    root.ctrls.primaryCtrl = primaryCtrl;
})(this, angular);

(function (root, angular) {
    root.ctrls = root.ctrls || {};

    var secondaryCtrl = function ($scope) {
        var self = this;
        console.log('secondaryCtrl constructor', self, $scope);
    };
    secondaryCtrl.prototype = angular.extend({},
        root.ctrls.primaryCtrl.prototype,
        {
            items: ['Stuff 1', 'Stuff 2']
        }
    );
    secondaryCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    root.ctrls.secondaryCtrl = secondaryCtrl;
})(this, angular);

var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('PrimaryCtrl', ctrls.primaryCtrl);
app.controller('SecondaryCtrl', ctrls.secondaryCtrl);
```

and

```
<div ng-controller="PrimaryCtrl as primary">
    <p ng-repeat="item in primary.items">{{item}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondaryCtrl as secondary">
    <p ng-repeat="item in secondary.items">{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

You may also check [Angular Classy](http://davej.github.io/angular-classy/), which brings opinionated but viable [extending syntax](https://github.com/wuxiaoying/classy-extends) to Angular.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I be able to access the primary controller if the controllers are separated in different files with IIFE?

Comment: Your best bet is to `require` it with build system of your choice or es6 modules. Otherwise you will have to export globals from IIFE to `window` like it is usually done, `(function (root) { var ctrl = ...; root.ctrl = ctrl; })(this);`. Keep in mind that you can always separate common methods into service and mixin them in controllers like `angular.extend(this, baseCtrlService)`, but managing dependencies by means of Angular in a big app like that will make the one shoot into his foot most times.

Comment: Thanks again. So how would you solve this "problem" where you have a lot of common controller code that you want to share? Would you say that DRY is mandatory here or could you just have 3-5 very similar controllers?

Comment: I guess you're already following 'thin controllers, fat services' principle, so there are no logic in controllers, only scope bindings. It depends on the amount of WET code, I would personally leave them as is or go ES6/TS classes for long-term project.