# how angular controller (and scope) inheritance works

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how controller inheritance works. I have three controllers:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'main';
    $scope.getName = function() {
        return $scope.name;
    };
}]);
myApp.controller('Child1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'child1';
}]);
myApp.controller('Child2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'child2';
}]);
```

and my view

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller='MainController'>
        <div ng-bind='getName()'></div>

        <div ng-controller='Child1'>
            <div ng-bind='getName()'></div>

            <div ng-controller='Child2'>
                <div ng-bind='getName()'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but they're all showing "main". How do I fix this?

here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g3xzh4ov/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMnpOWCaQehM00LGLKrm?p=preview) of how controllers can be extended in Angular.

```
myApp.service('baseCtrl', function () {
  this.name = 'base';
  this.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
  };
});

myApp.controller('MainController', ['baseCtrl', function (baseCtrl) {
  angular.extend(this, baseCtrl);
  this.name = 'main';
}]);
myApp.controller('Child1', ['baseCtrl', function (baseCtrl) {
  angular.extend(this, baseCtrl);
  this.name = 'child1';
}]);
myApp.controller('Child2', ['baseCtrl', function (baseCtrl) {
  angular.extend(this, baseCtrl);
  this.name = 'child2';
}]);
```

It obliges to use `controllerAs`, which replaces `$scope` with `this`, it is especially good for such cases.

Notice the usage of `service` instead of other Angular service types, it uses `new` under the hood, so `this...` statements can be brought right from a controller to separate service.

There are several ways of doing controller inheritance. Here is [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400979/instantiate-other-angularjs-controller-with-a-commoncontroller-when-using-iife/31439032#31439032).

Regarding the original code, there is no 'controller iheritance' in Angular. And `$scope` prototypical inheritance assumes that

```
$scope.getName = function() {
    return $scope.name;
};
```

returns `$scope.name` from the context where it was defined, it is `MainController` function in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're facing is actually based on core Javascript functionality.

You see, the confusion that you're facing stems from the mix of scoping, and prototypical inheritance. The properties are copied over, but the scoping remains the same, preventing you from accessing the variables that you expect to be able to access. To understand this better, perhaps instead of `$scope`, we can look at a simpler variable:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var a = 1;
    $scope.getName = function() {
        console.log(a); // -> 1
        console.log(b); // Error! `Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined`
    };
}]);
myApp.controller('Child1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var b = 2;
}]);
```

Obviously, `MainController` doesn't know that `Child1` defined some variable called `b`, so it errors. That variable is strictly out of lexical scope.

Likewise, if we renamed `b` to `a`, it won't turn the value in `MainController` to 2. This demonstrates exactly what's happening for you: you have three things called `$scope`, and only one is in the lexical scope.

Two options to fix it:

**1)** use `this`:

```
$scope.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
};
```

The `this` solution works because of how Javascript determines "this" based on context. Basically, since it's attached to a given `$scope` Object, that Object's a good candidate. But Mozilla can explain this better than I can, so view their page on the topic here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

**2)** Otherwise, you can simply pass the `$scope`:

```
$scope.getName = function(item) {
    return item.name;
};
```

Comment: It will work perfectly in his fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3xzh4ov/4/ . No other changes needed. Prototypical inheritance takes care of the problem (unless you use `bind`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite name property in child scopes ,convert your primitive name property into object.

```
$scope.user = {};
$scope.user.name='main';
    $scope.getName = function() {
        return $scope.user.name;
    };
```

And you should read [https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes](http://this) for detailed information.