# How to do $scope.$apply() with the new `controller as` syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS they have `$scope.$apply()` method to update the UI when there's a model change that is not done through normal AngularJS means.

In the more recent tutorials they recommend using the `<controller> as <object>` style of instantiating the objects and use `this` as the scope from their example

```
.controller('TodoListController', function() {
var todoList = this;
```

However `todoList.$apply()` does not appear to work.  Am I forced to use `$scope.$apply()` for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you have to use $scope.$apply(), but that's not a bad thing.

I had this same exact dilemma after reading that one should use controllerAs syntax. I even asked this question a few months later [In an isolate scope directive is there any difference between defining variables on scope and defining variables on the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708927/in-an-isolate-scope-directive-is-there-any-difference-between-defining-variables)

The answer, after thinking about this for a while, is that controllerAs syntax doesn't mean an aversion to `$scope`, but a design pattern to prevent global state from being stored in `$scope` because that's when you start nesting scopes, which leads to a lot of problems.

`$scope` isn't an evil thing. It just lets you screw yourself over, but if you need to use it you shouldn't stop yourself from doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Think you mean the "controller as" syntax, would be good to update the question title.  You can still inject $scope and use it for registering watches or whatever, typically you aren't calling $apply within a controller though, typically it's done in a directive in response to some event that changes the model and needs to trigger Angular to refresh.

Comment: I updated the title.  So it sounds like I'm forced to inject `$scope` if I wanted to use `$apply` then?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is pass this as bind parameter using either ES5 bind or angular.bind function

Eexmaple:

```js
myApp.controller("myController",['$scope',function(s){
   this.name="val1";
   console.log("1: "+this.name);
   setTimeout(function(){
     console.log("2: "+this.name);
 
     s.$apply(function(){
       this.name="val2";  
     }.bind(this));
     console.log("3: "+this.name);
   }.bind(this));
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly in the controller `this` refers to the controller

```
.controller('TodoListController', function() {
    var todoList = this;
```

Here todoList is the controller.

---

However **in** a method defined on the scope, `this` refers to the scope. So

```
.controller('TodoListController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        var todoList = this;
        ....
```

would have todoList pointing to the scope and you can do todoList.$apply()