# AngularJS - Should a controller call a service or factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When an angular controller needs to invoke some logic, like perhaps calling a web API, that logic can be encapsulated in an angular service or factory. (There are other options, but that's not important for the difference between a service and a factory.)

I just did some googling and there are a ton of articles and videos out there that explain what services and factories are. These articles and videos don't explain which one to use and why. So if I'm writing code in my angular controller and I want to use a factory or service, which one should I use and why?

I don't care about how they work, that at least one of them is a singleton, that  one returns and instance of a function, one is used with the new keyword, blah...

Both services and factories appear to be used and called in the same way. So can someone explain in which case I would use one over the other and why? Does it even matter?

** Edit **

The suggested possible answer states this:

> You can accomplish the same thing with both. However, in some cases
>   the factory gives you a little bit more flexibility to create an
>   injectable with a simpler syntax. That's because while
>   myInjectedService must always be an object, myInjectedFactory can be
>   an object, a function reference, or any value at all.

If that's it, then my question is indeed answered. But it would be nice to know if that's the case. Is that the only reason to use a factory over a service?

Comment: There are some good writeups at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324451/angular-service-vs-angular-factory/15914263

Comment: The answer lies in all the stuff that you don't care about (how they work, etc). In the end, they are both producing the same thing: a singleton object, that you can inject into other application components. Since they are producing the same result, it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: @JoePontani The problem I've found with all of these articles is that there is a lot of explanation about the difference between the two *internally*. Most of them don't talk about which one to use from the caller's perspective. I thought it would be nice to have one location where someone cuts through all of the details and just says: "Use this in this case. Here is why..."

Comment: The issue is that this question asks the same thing as the other question.  It even has the text "Which should be used for what (assuming they do different things)?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `factory` if object definition syntax is preferable

```
app.factory('factory', function () {
    ...
    return {
        value: '...'
    };
});
```

or it returns something that is not an object for some reason.

Use `service` if `this` syntax is preferable

```
app.service('service', function () {
    this.value = '...';
});
```

or it should return an object created with `new` from another constructor, e.g.

```
app.factory('factory', function () {
    return new someConstructor();
});
```

vs.

```
app.service('service', someConstructor);
```

A good use case for `service` is that you can seamlessly refactor existing controllers with `controllerAs` syntax to inherit from common service, in this case no `this` statements replacement is required, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640868/how-angular-controller-and-scope-inheritance-works/31641695#31641695):

```
app.service('parentControllerService', function () {
    this.value = '...';
});

app.controller('MainController', function (parentControllerService) {
    angular.extend(this, parentControllerService);
});

app.controller('ChildController', function (parentControllerService) {
    angular.extend(this, parentControllerService);
    this.value = '!!!';
});
```

Comment: What is "object definition syntax"?

Comment: `{ value: '...' }` - as opposed to defining `this` properties one by one, like `this.value = '...'`