# AngularJS forwarding/mixins?

Tags: angularjs, inheritance

I find myself often writing one service that wrap rest api (`ApiService`), then another service that wrap some business logic around it (`ActionDispatcher`), and then I need it in various controllers.

So `ControllerA` have:

```
...
$scope.funA = () => { ActionDispatcher.funA() };
$scope.funB = () => { ActionDispatcher.funB() };
$scope.funC = () => { this->funC_reimplemented() };
...
```

While `ControllerB` have:

```
...
$scope.funA = () => { ActionDispatcher.funA() };
$scope.funB = () => { this.funB_reimplemented() };
$scope.funC = () => { ActionDispatcher.funC() };
...
```

**Is there Angular Way for something like?**

```
function ControllerA(...) {
  functionsFrom(ActionDispatcher);
  ...
  $scope.funC = () => { this->funC_reimplemented() };
  ...
```

`functionsFrom` desired behavior:

- Only copy functions (I want my `ControllerA` and `ControllerB` to just delegate responsibilities to `ActionDispatcher`)
- Attach those new functions to `$scope`
- (Optionally) Attach those new functions to provided object (so `ControllerA As vm` still works)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how angular controller (and scope) inheritance works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640868/how-angular-controller-and-scope-inheritance-works)

Comment: Nope. Its not. Due to how inheritance of `$scope` works one Controller need to be tied to html element/comment/whatnot placed **inside** other. So whatnot "hosting" `ControllerA` would need to be wrapping whatnow "hosting" `ControllerB`, end even then its one way inheritance. Unrelated to my `ActionDispatcher` service too.

Comment: There's no mention in the original question of what you've just said. Please, provide more code and some information how it is supposed to be used. It is not clear what you're trying to achieve, and the fact that you're sticking to '$scope' instead of 'this' with ES6/TS syntax doesn't add clarity, too.

Comment: Edited my question. I want to defenitevly forward some of controller functions to service functions. Have nothing to do with `$scope` inheritance. (Or maybe it do, but I do not know how..)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it has to be

```
app.value('bindMethods', (obj) => {
  var boundObj;

  if (angular.isObject(obj)) {
    boundObj = {};
    angular.forEach(obj, (fn, key) => {
      if (typeof fn !== 'function')
        return;
      boundObj[key] = angular.bind(obj, fn);
    });
  }

  return boundObj;
});

function ControllerA(ActionDispatcher, bindMethods) {
  angular.extend($scope, bindMethods(ActionDispatcher));
  // or
  // angular.extend(this, bindMethods(ActionDispatcher));
  ...
```

Wrapping them in closures will require additional measures for passing arguments, that's essentially the job that `angular.bind` does (which in its turn provides a replacement for native `Function.prototype.bind`).