# How to share common logic between controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two pages and two controllers that perform searches on the same dataset. One has a simple form to specify search criteria. The other allows the user to select data on a map (by selecting an area or clicking on features on the map).

The result of the search is then displayed on a data table below the search controls (on the same page).

So, the controllers have different search features, but also share a lot of common behaviour, i.e. displaying the grid, paging, reloading, batch edition of data from the grid etc.

As a result, there are several functions that are repeated, sometimes with slight variations, sometimes exactly identical, in both controllers.

The part of the page that displays the data is also a shared template, included with `ng-include` on both search pages.

Here is an example :

```
$scope.selectAllRows = function(){

    var selectedItems = $scope.searchState.selectedItems;

    angular.forEach($scope.searchState.searchResult.rows, function(row){
        // add only if not already selected
        if(selectedItems.indexOf(row) < 0){
            selectedItems.push(row);
        }
    });

};
```

This function selects all the rows in the table. It is bound to the `ng-click` of a button on the page.

There are many other functions like this, that basically read some state from the `$scope`, perform some logic, and place something new back to the `$scope`.

I would like to remove the duplication of these functions and regroup the common behaviour in a single unit of code.

**Note : what I am trying to share here is behaviour, not data. These functions will perform the same logic, but on different scopes.**

Since these are really presentation / UI stuff, and need to be put on the `$scope`, I don't think a service could be used because the `$scope` is a strictly controller thing and cannot be injected into services.

I am experimenting with defining a standalone function, in a different file, and calling this function from both controller :

```
myapp.defineCommonControllerBehaviour = function($scope, someOtherService){
    $scope.selectAlRows = function(){....}

    $scope.someOtherCommonTask = function(){
         someOtherService.doTheTask();
    }

    //etc...
};

//controller 1
myapp.defineCommonBehaviour($scope, someOtherService);

//controller 2
myapp.defineCommonBehaviour($scope, someOtherService);
```

It works but is not very elegant, since it defines a function in the global scope, outside of any Angular module.

Is there a angular native way of achieving this ? Or at least more in line with the Angular architecture ?

Comment: Sounds like you need a base controller (to establish common functionality from and extend as necessary). A search of SO shows several variations, and Google with lend itself to even more. (e.g. [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/03/25/AngularJS-A-better-way-to-implement-a-base-controller.aspx) is just 1 (of many) examples, and passes `$scope` to the base, which I feel is what you're looking for).

Comment: seems like you need move your grid functionality to directive

Comment: Don't use a base controller, as you won't to avoid $scope inheritance, and functions on base controller are not passed to directives with isolated scope. Common functionality should be part of a service (logic) or a directive (view component).

Answer (score 2):

There are some patterns which I found to be useful for my use cases.

Either [neutral JS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400979/instantiate-other-angularjs-controller-with-a-commoncontroller-when-using-iife/31439032#31439032) can be used to define and inherit your controllers (the lack of dependency management and prototype inheritance don't make it the best option, but ES2015 classes are a great help in this case).

Or the one can make use of Angular dependency management and [store common methods and properties in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640868/how-angular-controller-and-scope-inheritance-works/31641695#31641695):

```
myApp.service('baseCtrl', function () {
  this.name = 'base';
  this.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
  };
});

myApp.controller('MainController', ['baseCtrl', function (baseCtrl) {
  angular.extend(this, baseCtrl);
  this.name = 'main';
}]);
```

There are third-party solutions such as [Classy](https://github.com/wuxiaoying/classy-extends) that provide opinionated inheritance syntax for controllers.

`$injector` or `$controller` can be also used to get access to parent controller and inherit it, but since `controllerAs` syntax was introduced, there's no need to mess around `$scope` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Put common functions into `commonCtrl`'s scope and access them in child controller. Angular child's `scope` inherit from parent's `scope`.

```
<div ng-controller='commonCtrl'>
    <div ng-controller='featureOneCtrl'></div>
</div>
<div ng-controller='commonCtrl'>
    <div ng-controller='featureTwoCtrl'></div>
</div>
```